Compare substring from Array 1 to strings in multiple arrays
Problem: I have multiple tables. If all the keywords from table1 are matching in other tables, say table2 and table3, than store table1 values in a DataTable or List. If not, then store it in another DT or List.
For simplicity I will take only 3 arrays. Later I can extend it. So, I will store table1 in a array of string - arrayMain, other two arrays would be arrayData1 and arrayData2. So, arrayData1 and arrayData2 are linked. For example, consider arrayData1 as list of employee names and arrayData2 as their addresses.
What I have tried:
//Fixed array size around 1000
string[] arrayMain = {"some&set&of&string&with&Ampersent&As&Delimeter",
"other&set&of&string&with&Ampersent&As&Delimeter",
"another&set&of&string&with&Ampersent&As&Delimeter", "and so on"...};

//array size more than arrayMain, say around 3000-4000
string[] arrayData1 = {"some set of string, with special characters, numbers and more.,",
"next set of string, may have special characters, numbers and more.",
"another set strings, with special characters, numbers and more.,", "and so on"...};

//this array size is same as arrayData1
string[] arrayData2 = {"some set of string, with special characters, numbers and more.,",
"next set of string, may have special characters, numbers and more.",
"another set strings, with special characters, numbers and more.,", "and so on"...};

List<string> matched = new List<string>();
            List<string> UnMatched = new List<string>();

        foreach (string str in arrayMain)
        {
            //split the words in the string to compare each & every word with the strings of arrayData1 & arrayData2
            string[] MainSplit = str.Split('&');
            bool mat = false; 

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayData1.Length; i++)
            {
                //if arrayData1 & arrayData2 contains all the strings in MainSplit than add it to a DT or List.
                if (MainSplit.Any(s => s.IndexOf(arrayData1[i], StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1) &&
                    MainSplit.Any(s => s.IndexOf(arrayData2[i], StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1))
                {
                    matched.Add(str);
                    mat = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (mat == false)
                UnMatched.Add(str);
        }
    }

Let me explain with an example:
MainSplit = {"some", "exapmle", "string", "here" }
arrayData1[i] = {"some", "other", "string"}
arrayData2[i] = {"other", "example", "string", "here"}

Here, arrayData1[i] and arrayData2[i] contains all of the strings from MainSplit. So, its a 100% match and in this case MainSplit or str can be added to the list matched.
I need help with this. Can anyone point me in right direction?

I think you might be looking for Check whether an array is a subset of another.

@AndrewMorton I don't think so. this wont work for multiple comparison

What problem did you find when extending it?
